# SVG filter to map alpha values to RGB values in a table?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I see how to use [feComponentTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComponentTransfer) to adjust RGBA values using a `table` and `tableValues`.

But is there a way to adjust the R, G, or B values using alpha values as input (for example)?

Why?  Say I composite many translucent shapes, resulting in different opacities where these shapes overlap.  I would like to use these opacity values to adjust the RGB using a lookup table based on the opacity of each pixel.

[image: gray scale ellipse, squares, and text overlapping]

For example, in [this image](https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/gZrwOM) the ellipse, squares, and text are drawn with alpha 0.1.  Overlapping regions have higher alpha values.

How would I map every pixel in this image with alpha 0.1 to `rgba(255,0,0,1)` and everywhere with alpha 0.2 to `rgba(0,255,0,1)` (and interpolate the replacement colors between those two alpha values on the anti-aliased edges)?  More colors would be assigned to all other alpha values up to 1.

Easy to make such a lookup table.

But how to apply to image with a svg filter?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to catch the alpha layer and assign each alpha value different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it, but it is a multistep process, and you'll have to see about performance and maintainability yourself.

My example code divides the opacity values into four equally-spaced ranges: 0.2...0.4...0.6...0.8...1. The range 0...0.2 is mapped to transparency.

For each of the four colored ranges you need to combine three filter primitives:

- pick up `SourceAlpha` as input, and apply `<feComponentTransfer>` to the alpha channel with type `discrete` such that only one range is mapped to `opacity="1"`
- fill the filter area with `<feFlood>` in the assigned color
- combine the first and second result with `<feComposite>` and `operator="in"`, so that only the mapped values are colored

Then, merge all the different monochromatic parts together with `<feMerge>`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <linearGradient id="sourceGradient" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0" y2="0">
    <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0" offset="0" />
    <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
  <filter id="filter">
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step1">
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 0 0 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,0,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step1" result="color1" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step2">
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 1 0 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,255,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step2" result="color2" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step3">
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,255,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step3" result="color3" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step4">
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 1"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,255)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step4" result="color4" />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="color1" />
      <feMergeNode in="color2" />
      <feMergeNode in="color3" />
      <feMergeNode in="color4" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <rect fill="url(#sourceGradient)" x="50" y="25" width="300" height="50" id="rect" />
  <use xlink:href="#rect" y="100" filter="url(#filter)" />
</svg>
```

> interpolate the replacement colors between those two alpha values on the anti-aliased edges

I am not sure I understand that, but `type="table"` for component transfer results in a continuous scale. The result after merge has opacities below 1 in most places, so you would need some final steps to ramp that up again.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <linearGradient id="sourceGradient" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0" y2="0">
    <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0" offset="0" />
    <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
  <filter id="filter" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step1">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1 0 0 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,0,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step1" result="color1" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step2">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 1 0 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,255,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step2" result="color2" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step3">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,255,0)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step3" result="color3" />
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="step4">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 1"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,255)" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="step4" result="color4" />
    <feMerge result="merged">
      <feMergeNode in="color1" />
      <feMergeNode in="color2" />
      <feMergeNode in="color3" />
      <feMergeNode in="color4" />
    </feMerge>
    <feComponentTransfer  in="SourceAlpha" result="capped">
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feComposite operator="atop" in="merged" in2="capped" />
  </filter>
  <rect fill="url(#sourceGradient)" x="50" y="25" width="300" height="50" id="rect" />
  <use xlink:href="#rect" y="100" filter="url(#filter)" />
</svg>
```